# Numeric ID type in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to define an ID type with a given pattern using XML schema. What I have so far is this:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="myid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
      <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9_-]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

This works except that e.g. `<myid>00123_45678<myid>` does not validate. Apparently, the base type xs:ID requires its values to XML non-qualified names (xs:NCName). In particular, IDs may not start with numbers.

Is there an alternative way to define a document wide identifier using XML schema that allows for numeric first character?

Comment: Can you just use `xs:string` as the base? Or have I missed something?

Comment: I would lose the uniqueness constraint then.

Comment: Maybe with an `<xs:assert>` on your attribute (only in XML Schema **1.1**)?

Comment: If you can scope to a common ancestor rather than ID/IDREF's document-wide scoping, consider key/keyref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive your type from xsd:string or xsd:token or xsd:NMTOKEN, not ID.  The xsd:ID type enforces the XML name rules and thus requires the value to begin with a namestart character.

Recover the uniqueness constraint by adding an xs:unique declaration to the appropriate ancestor element.

Comment: Apparently, this is the only way to do it. It will not work for me though, because I do not have a suitable ancestor element. Therefore, I will need to sacrifice uniqueness within the document and ensure it on application level instead.

Comment: You don't know what elements in the schema may appear as ancestors?  as document elements?